# How do I remove punctuation from a string in a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove punctuation from a pandas Series. My problem is that I am unable to iterate over all the lines in the Series. This is the code that I tried out but it is taking forever to run. Note that my dataset is a bit large, around 112MB(200,000 rows)

```
import pandas as pd
import string

df = pd.read_csv('let us see.csv')
s = set(string.punctuation)

for st in df.reviewText.str:
    for j in s:
        if j in st:
            df.reviewText = df.reviewText.str.replace(j, '')

df.reviewText = df.reviewText.str.lower()
df['clean_review'] = df.reviewText
print(df.clean_review.tail())
```

Comment: why do you iterate over the series? you can replace the whole series at once `for j in s: df.reviewText.str.replace(j, "")` and replace all occurences, withoiut checking before.

Comment: You're right. Thank you. But it doesn't work. The punctuations are still there

Comment: if you want to replace the values inplace, you need to use `inplace=True` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: got it. god bless. thank you so much have a good day

Answer (score 0):

D-E-N's answer is pretty good. I just add another solution of how to improve the performance of your code.
Iteraring over a list version of your series should work faster than your approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import string

def replace_chars(text, chars):
    for c in chars:
        text = text.replace(c, '')
    return text.lower()

df = pd.read_csv('let us see.csv')
s = set(string.punctuation)

reviewTextList = df.reviewText.astype(str).tolist()
reviewTextList = [replace_chars(x, s) for x in reviewTextList]

df['clean_review'] = reviewTextList
print(df.clean_review.tail())
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you so much. One more thing though. Can you help me out with using value_counts() in my df['reviewText'] column? I want to check how many times each word appears in the Series. Should I use groupby? If yes, then how do I iterate over each row separately?

Sample screenshot: https://imgur.com/HzjMWlc